# is Eclipse/Californium CoAP observer much slower than Aiocoap observer?

Tags: java, udp, network-protocols, coap, californium

I'm trying to build a system in which I can connect some devices to a server over the internet.
I want to stream some data over CoAP (10-30FPS), frame size = 3KB.
Firstly, I used Aiocoap, it sends up to 100FPS but uses too much CPU,
requests are NON, got low lose rate in Aiocoap,
while Eclipse/Californium could not send more than 3FPS,
when i use higher FPS, either I receive only the first block of each message or receiving nothing, also not ordered most of the times.

I was wondering if this is the real performance of Californium  or am I using it in a wrong way?

I will share some code:

*server.java*

```
static class CoapObserverServer extends CoapResource {
                int i = -1;
                public CoapObserverServer() {
                        super("alarm");
                        setObservable(true); // enable observing
                        setObserveType(Type.NON); // configure the notification type to CONs
                        getAttributes().setObservable(); // mark observable in the Link-Format

                        System.out.println(this);
                        // schedule a periodic update task, otherwise let events call changed()
                        //new Timer().schedule(new UpdateTask(), 0, 1000/2);
                }
                private class UpdateTask extends TimerTask {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                changed(); // notify all observers
                        }
                }

                @Override
                public void handleGET(CoapExchange exchange) {
                        // the Max-Age value should match the update interval
                        exchange.setMaxAge(1);
                        //++i;
                        int leng = 2000;
                        String s = "" + i + "-" + fillString('X', leng - 1 - Integer.toString(i).len>
                        exchange.respond(s);
                }
                public static String fillString(char fillChar, int count){
                        // creates a string of 'x' repeating characters
                        char[] chars = new char[count];
                        while (count>0) chars[--count] = fillChar;
                        return new String(chars);
                }

                @Override
                public void handleDELETE(CoapExchange exchange) {
                        delete(); // will also call clearAndNotifyObserveRelations(ResponseCode.NOT_>
                        exchange.respond(ResponseCode.DELETED);
                }

                @Override
                public void handlePUT(CoapExchange exchange) {
                        exchange.accept();

                        int format = exchange.getRequestOptions().getContentFormat();
                        if (format == MediaTypeRegistry.TEXT_PLAIN) {
                                 // ...
                                        String plain = exchange.getRequestText();
                                try{
                                        i = Integer.valueOf(plain);
                                } catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                                        System.out.println("error converting string"+ plain);
                                }
                                exchange.respond(ResponseCode.CHANGED);
                                changed(); // notify all observers
                        }
                }
```

*Observer.java*

```
private static final File CONFIG_FILE = new File("Californium3.properties");
    private static final String CONFIG_HEADER = "Californium CoAP Properties file for client";
    private static final int DEFAULT_MAX_RESOURCE_SIZE = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2 MB
    private static final int DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE = 512;

    static {
        CoapConfig.register();
        UdpConfig.register();
    }

    private static DefinitionsProvider DEFAULTS = new DefinitionsProvider() {

        @Override
        public void applyDefinitions(Configuration config) {
            config.set(CoapConfig.MAX_RESOURCE_BODY_SIZE, DEFAULT_MAX_RESOURCE_SIZE);
            config.set(CoapConfig.MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE, DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE);
            config.set(CoapConfig.PREFERRED_BLOCK_SIZE, DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE);
        }
    };

    private static class AsynchListener implements CoapHandler {
        @Override
        public void onLoad(CoapResponse response) {
            System.out.println( response.getResponseText() );
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            System.err.println("Error");
        }
    }

    /*
     * Application entry point.
     */ 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Configuration config = Configuration.createWithFile(CONFIG_FILE, CONFIG_HEADER, DEFAULTS);
        Configuration.setStandard(config);

        URI uri = null; // URI parameter of the request
        if (args.length > 0) {

            // input URI from command line arguments
            try {
                uri = new URI(args[0]);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                System.err.println("Invalid URI: " + e.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
            }

            CoapClient client = new CoapClient(uri);
            client.useNONs();
            // observe
            AsynchListener asynchListener = new AsynchListener();
            CoapObserveRelation observation = client.observe(asynchListener);
            
            // User presses ENTER to exit
            System.out.println("Press ENTER to exit...");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            try { br.readLine(); } catch (IOException e) { }
            System.out.println("Exiting...");
            observation.proactiveCancel();
            
        }
```

So i'm controlling the FPS by sending PUT requests with a server that has a counter 0-50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, what your doing.
That seems to be wired and not related to RFC7252 nor RFC7641.

CoAP is designed for REST, I don't see any benefit in using it for video streaming.

Using Eclipse/Californium on a Intel n6005 with 16GB RAM, the CoAP/DTLS server runs on about 60000 requests/second. The benchmark uses 2000 clients in parallel.

See also [Eclipse/Californium - Benchmarks j5005](https://github.com/eclipse-californium/californium/tree/main/demo-apps/cf-extplugtest-server#benchmarks)

Using only one client with CON requests, the performance is mainly limited by the RTT. 30 requests/second should work, if that RTT is accordingly small.

Using NON requests doesn't really help. CoAP RFC7252 defines two layers, a messaging layer and an application layer. NON affects only the messaging layer, but a NON request will wait for it's response, if NSTART-1 should be used.

If your RTT is the issue, you may try to escape that either using requests with "No Server Response" (RFC7967) or multiple NON responses (RFC7641). The first is not intended for  fast requests, the second is more a work-around of the initial statement, that CoAP is REST not video-streaming.

So, what is your RTT?

Comment: So, if CoAP is not suitable for streaming videos to constrained devices,
What protocol do you suggest?
I'm trying different protocols to get highest FPS for streaming over the internet.

Comment: about the "multiple NON responses (RFC7641)", This is what I am actually doing, which means a client as A NON observer and another client to make multiple PUT requests to the server (resource), and yea the RTT is not small.

Comment: Video streaming isn't my domain.

Comment: > "this is what I am actually doing" such a "relay" approach is even harder than just stream between two peers. If you use "large frames", they split into blockwise, which takes even several round trips. if you notify the other clients, that a new frame has arrived, all pending transfers are canceled (that may be the difference to other servers, Californium just forward the newest version of the resource.)